# Having trouble installing SVN through zip Windows

Tags: svn

In the instructions for installing svn on windows through zip, I've come across a few hardships. The SVN I've downloaded is version 1.8.13. In the instructions, it says to add the bin directory in the Subversion folder to the path environment but there is no bin folder.

To test the installation, they tell me to run 'svn co https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk svn' in the directory of the files "C:\Users\dt208672\Documents\subversion-1.8.13\subversion". However, i get the error 'svn is not recognized as an internal or external command'

Comment: If my answer is the accepted answer for the question then you should accept it by clicking the hollow check mark next to the answer, so that it becomes green. If you found a different solution then you should describe it here and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no bin folder in the package then you have the wrong package. Download the package from the link below, and in it there is a `bin` folder:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/files/1.8.13/apache24/svn-win32-1.8.13-ap24.zip

Or this one for Apache 2.2:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/files/1.8.13/apache22/svn-win32-1.8.13.zip